# jQuery(...).kendoDatePicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Risking to get my reputation downsized, I am new to Kendo UI and stuff, and I read a lot about this error, but couldn't find anything to help me.

Here is my view

```
@model ClothingSite.Models.Register
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ThunderBird Clothes";
}
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>

</head>

<h2>Title Legend</h2>
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("Birthday"))
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/kendo.common.min.css")">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/kendo.default.min.css")">
```

Am I missing any reference?I have the scripts from the Free Trial Telerik Kendo UI
And the full error

> IndexButton:78 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).kendoDatePicker is not
>   a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (IndexButton:78)
>       at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the main kendo ui JS file. based on your kendo ui version you can add kendo.all.min.js file in your project.

For step by step guidance please look into [this](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/asp-net-mvc-5).

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: still the same error.    `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script> `

Comment: I have added link in my last my post for reference.

Comment: Open your developer tool in chrome and check the network tab. Your file may not have been loaded properly.

Comment: @roland Everything is loaded properly. I did that to check which of the .js files couldn't been found and everything is loaded.

Comment: Remove the last two scripts. Test. Add the latest one. Test. I suspect that the last two scripts are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Also I think you don't need kendo.web.min.js if you're going with kendo.all.min.js.

Comment: Yes "kendo.web.min.js" is not required if we use "kendo.all.min.js"

Comment: Thank you guys foe every advice! It works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by ensuring there weren't duplicate calls to jquery.  In my case (I'm using ASP.Net Core) I found a reference to jquery.min.js in the default layout of the application, e.g.

```
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">
```

I also was including Telerik's supported version of JQuery using this link (Note the version numbers in the url that should match the version of Telerik you are using):

```
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My fix was simply to remove the version that came with my template and used the tested version with Telerik.